# Making Tags in HTML

Tags: html, tags

I'm relatively new to html and didn't know that you can't really use a "tab" for indentation.  I sorta just typed this out in my html code before I knew about making classes and it sorta just works:

```
<tab style = "text-decoration: underline;"> text goes here </tab>
```

Here, the only thing tab does it act as something to contain the "style = 'text-decoration: underline;' " - which is exactly what I want it to do luckily enough.

So my question is *how and why* does this work?

I looked up other posts like this one: [Making Custom HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451196/making-custom-html-tags) and it doesn't really help explain how I'm able to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For forwards compatibility with elements that might be added to HTML in the future, unknown elements are supported with very basic default styling and support for global attributes.

If an element of that name is added in the future, it will be incompatible with your use of it.

Write valid, semantic HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add what to Quentin said:

I would assume that you are trying to reuse this multiple times? Use CSS classes when using styling that needs to be used multiple times. You can use  or something similar to do what you want to accomplish. Inner styling tends to make things hard to read and makes it non reusable.

If you're asking about how websites like YouTube do this, they use a JavaScript framework such as React or Vue to make custom "components". Beyond rendering issues with styling, beyond not working, it will cause your HTML to fail HTML5 validation.

Answer (score -1):

Nope tab is not a valid HTML tag consider using css styling for this such as:

```
<p style="text-indent: 5px;">text goes here</p>
```

text-indent is a CSS property to well... indent your text. Here is a w3schools tutorial for it

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp

Edit: can you also share your complete code so we can understand how and why is this happening including your CSS

Regards.